# Child component not updating on props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a little trouble updating the my child component in react. I have my `SettingsForm` component that uses a `Switch` child component.

`Switch` accepts `updateValue` method as a prop and uses that to update the value for the `on` prop in the parent component. For some reason the `on` prop value isn't propagating through to the child. On initial load the component sets properly but after that it never reflects changes in the parent. I can console and see the values in the parent being changed but the child never updates.

I've used this child component in a class component before and it works fine. Having issues in a function component.

SettingsForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { Input, Label } from 'reactstrap'
import Switch from '../../../../components/Input/Switch/Switch'

export default function SettingsForm ({ settingOne, settingTwo, enabled, updateSettings}) {
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
        settingOne: settingOne,
        settingTwo: settingTwo,
        enabled: enabled
    })

    /**
     * Update values for select inputs
     * 
     * @param {event} event 
     */
    const updateSwitch = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name
        const value = event.target.checked

        settings[name] = value
        setSettings(settings)
    }

    return (
        <div className={"settings-form"}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-1">
                            <Switch                
                                id={'settingOne'}
                                name={'settingOne'}
                                value={settingOne}
                                on={settingOne}
                                updateValue={updateSwitch}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">Turn Setting One On</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-1">
                            <Switch        
                                id={'settingTwo'}
                                name={'settingTwo'}
                                value={settingTwo}
                                on={settingTwo}
                                updateValue={updateSwitch}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">Turn Setting Two On</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-1">
                            <Switch                                                     
                                name={'enabled'}
                                value={enabled}
                                id={'enabled'}
                                on={enabled}
                                updateValue={updateSwitch}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">Enable Item</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <button type="button" onClick={updateSettings(settings)}>Update Settings</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Switch.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from './switch.css';

class Switch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <label className={style.switch}>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name={this.props.name}
                        id={this.props.id}
                        onClick={this.props.updateValue}
                        checked={this.props.on}
                        onChange={() => {}}
                    />
                    <span className={style.slider + ' ' + style.round}></span>
                </label>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Switch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mutating the `settings` object, React doesn't think it has been updated when you call `setSettings`.

You can instead create a copy of the `settings` object and update your state with that.

```
const updateSwitch = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  const newSettings = { ...settings, [name]: value };
  setSettings(newSettings);
};
```